# How can I make my 'for' statement work fine, and how can I calculate the total?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class score {
private:
    int marks;
    int total;
public:
public:
    score(){ marks = 0; total = 0; }
    void getM();
    void tot();
    void displayM();
    void cinM();
};
```

```cpp
void score::displayM()
{
    cout << "The score is " << total << endl;
}

void score::getM()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= subjects; i++)
        cout << "Enter the score of the subject " << i << endl;
    cin >> marks;
}
   
void score::tot()
{
    total = total + marks;
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter the score of the subject 0
Enter the score of the subject 1
Enter the score of the subject 2
Enter the score of the subject 3
Enter the score of the subject 4
Enter the score of the subject 5
// once i write any number it just print 
The score is 3
```

The output in my mind is:

```
Enter the score of the subject 0 3
Enter the score of the subject 1 3
Enter the score of the subject 2 1
Enter the score of the subject 3 3
Enter the score of the subject 4 3
Enter the score of the subject 5 2
The score is 15
```

Comment: I edited the code in the question to "fix" the indentation. It should make it easier to see *one* problem with the code (there are more problems and potential problems with it).

Comment: Without seeing the rest of `score` and how you are using it in the rest of your code, it is very difficult to help you. Please provide a [mcve]. However, that being said, one problem in the code you HAVE shown is that in `getM()`, the `cin >> marks;` statement is *outside* the `for` loop, when it needs to be *inside* the loop instead. You need to add `{ }` braces to your loop, eg: `for (int i = 0; i <= subjects; i++) { cout << "Enter the score of the subject " << i << endl; cin >> marks; ... }` Of course, you need to actually *do something* with `marks` on each loop iteration.

Comment: @BlahblahBlah that information should have been added to your question as an [edit], not a comment. In any case, where is `subjects` defined and assigned? What does `main()` look like? Again, we need a [mcve].

Comment: if added the {} and thanks to that i could add the score individually and i added the same for statement at the tot() function and it worked great ... Thanks

Comment: Of course it is, because you are not adding the individual marks to `total` on each loop iteration. `score::tot()` only sees the last mark that was entered. You would need to either 1) sum up each mark into `marks` in the loop, so that `total + marks` makes sense after the loop is finished, or else 2) add `marks` to `total` on each loop iteration, and get rid of `tot()`.  Either way, your `score` class as shown is pretty useless.

Comment: That's easy. just put the UI-related logic outside. Let me try to generate an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void score::getM()
{
    cin >> marks;
    tot();
}
```

And then in main,

```
// main.cpp
int main() {
    score s;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the score of the subject " << i+1 << endl;
        s.getM();
    }
    s.displayM();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a demo with full code:

```
// main.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class score {
private:
    int marks;
    int total;
public:
public:
    score(){ marks = 0; total = 0; }
    void getM() {
        cin >> marks;
        tot();
    }
    void tot() {
        total = total + marks;
    }
    void displayM() { 
        cout << "The score is " << total << endl; 
    }
};


int main() {
    score s;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the score of the subject " << i+1 << endl;
        s.getM();
    }
    s.displayM();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile and run

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp
./a.out
```

The output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
Enter the score of the subject 1
1
Enter the score of the subject 2
2
Enter the score of the subject 3
3
Enter the score of the subject 4
4
Enter the score of the subject 5
5
The score is 15
```